# java - accesing the superclass and the interface of an object

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, superclass

I am writing a simple game in which you can choose to be different kinds of animals. `Animals` are subclasses of `Entity()` wich is a subclass of `GameObject()` I also created an interface `IPlayableAnimal` for the animals that you can play as. So when a `Player` object gets created you need to pass it a `IPlayableAnimal`. Now this works fine but I also want to access the `Entity` specific methods, but since a `PlayableAnimal` gets passed I can only use the methods form `IPlayableAnimal` (overwritten by it's subclass of course).

Is there a way to access to the `Entity` methods? Or do I have to make a subclass of `Entity` with the abstract methods of the `IPlayableAnimal` interface or passing a `IPlayableAnimal` and a `Entity` object to the `Player` object.

```
public class Player extends Entity {

  private IPlayableAnimal character;

  public Player(int x, int y, IPlayableAnimal character) {
      this(x, y, character, true);
  }

  public Player(int x, int y, IPlayableAnimal character, boolean visible) {
      super(x, y, visible, true); // the last true is for the hasAI boolean
  }

  protected void defineTasks() {
      tasks.add(new PlayerControlTask(this, 5));
  }

}
```

Comment: Create an `IEntity` interface and have your `IPlayableAnimal` extend it. Have `Entity` implement it.

Comment: Hmm, yeah had not thought of that yet. Thanks!